# How to plot with TiKz the following performance?

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot some percentages as lines. So I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(.9,0.9),anchor=north east}},
symbolic x coords={Accuracy, score, recall, precision, hamming loss, jaccard similarity, F-beta score}, xtick=data]

\addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
(Accuracy,12.90129) (score,34.908839) (recall,60.29032309) (precision,22.09321093) (hamming loss,50.3093) (jaccard similarity,90.2323) (F-beta score,89.1920129)
};

\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},blue,thick,dashed] coordinates {
(Accuracy,32.90129) (score,14.908839) (recall,10.29032309) (precision,26.09321093) (hamming loss,40.3093) (jaccard similarity,90.2323) (F-beta score,39.1920129)
};
\addlegendentry{data set 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this in order to see a line plot type?.

Comment: The move to close this seems a little harsh: this was migrated from stackoverflow only *seven* hours ago and the OP has made a good effort at doing the work themselves.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand from your question what you are trying to do but looking at your plot I think that you just want to move the legend box: this can be one using `legend style`. In addition, the labels on the axis bump into each other so you probably want to use `x tick label style` to rotate them. All of this is described in detail in the [pgfplots manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

With these in place your graph becomes:

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend style={at={(.9,0.9),anchor=north east}},
             symbolic x coords={Accuracy, score, recall, precision, hamming loss,
             jaccard similarity, F-beta score}, xtick=data,
             x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
             legend style={cells={anchor=east}, legend pos=outer north east,}
]

\addplot[mark=diamond*,thick,red] coordinates {
    (Accuracy,12.90129)
    (score,34.908839)
    (recall,60.29032309)
    (precision,22.09321093)
    (hamming loss,50.3093)
    (jaccard similarity,90.2323)
    (F-beta score,89.1920129)
};

\addlegendentry{data set 1}
\addplot[mark=o,mark options={solid},blue,thick,dashed] coordinates {
    (Accuracy,32.90129)
    (score,14.908839)
    (recall,10.29032309)
    (precision,26.09321093)
    (hamming loss,40.3093)
    (jaccard similarity,90.2323)
    (F-beta score,39.1920129)
};
\addlegendentry{data set 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Btw, I found your code really hard to read: if you add a little space and regularity I think it's easy to see what is going on.